# How do I remove this line in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

So, this [problem I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eltsA.png) is ruining the looks of the game I'm making. I don't know what it is, but I don't know how to remove it.

I was wondering if maybe there was a component I didn't color so I ran this, and it still didn't change anything.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < comboBox.getComponentCount(); i++) 
    {
        if ( comboBox.getComponent(i) instanceof JComponent) 
        {
            ( (JComponent) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 0, 0, 0, 0) );
            ( (JComponent) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setBackground( background );
            ( (JComponent) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setForeground( foreground );
        }


        if ( comboBox.getComponent(i) instanceof AbstractButton) 
        {
            ( (AbstractButton) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setBorderPainted( false );
            ( (AbstractButton) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setBackground( background );
            ( (AbstractButton) comboBox.getComponent( i ) ).setForeground( foreground);
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any ideas that would be helpful.

Comment: 1) Look to use a renderer. [`JComboBox.setRenderer(ListCellRenderer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setRenderer(javax.swing.ListCellRenderer)) BTW: Not clear from the code snippet, but don't put components in a combo, just data or POJs that the renderer acts on. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Did you notice the same line next to the button that displays the `JComboBox` drop-down list? You don't want to get rid of that line as well?

Comment: I want to get rid of both, yes, but the bigger one is the most annoying

Comment: *"I want to get rid of both"* Both of my comments? Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.